# How do I Integrate my API with my next js?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, next.js

So I'm pretty new to development, it's been like a month and a half since I started learning. So right now I'm stuck, I've got my Login API ready in spring boot which worked with postman and I've got my login page ready in next js. All I need now is when I click login it should authenticate the user details and move me to another page otherwise show something like 'invalid username/password. So how do I go about this, my js knowledge is pretty mediocre.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest starting with using a library to manage API calls,

I recommend Axios https://github.com/axios/axios.

Or Next's own library, SWR https://swr.vercel.app.

For authentication, many strategies exist, from using a JWT token to using session cookies. try searching and finding the best strategy for your app or your needs.

After that, try reading the different methods of data fetching that Next.JS offers https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview, you will find that each method helps to solve a certain problem, and has its own pros and cons.

Good Luck!